Confusion about Caching with Decorators in Python
I'm working with Python decorators to implement caching for functions. I understand the basic concept of caching results to improve performance, but I'm struggling with how to handle different function arguments and ensure the cache updates when the underlying data changes.
I've implemented a basic decorator that stores function results in a dictionary based on arguments. However, this approach doesn't handle situations where the function arguments might have complex structures (like nested lists) or when the underlying data the function relies on might be modified.
def simple_cache(func):
  cache = {}
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    key = (args, kwargs)  # Basic key based on arguments
    if key not in cache:
      cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return cache[key]
  return wrapper

@simple_cache
def calculate_something(data):
  # Simulates complex calculation
  # ...
  return result


This is a good try to understand the caching mechanism called memoization.

inputs: As you are using dictionary caching for positional and keyword arguments, they have to be hashable for the cache to work, whatever their complexity.

outputs: For the result of the cached function calls, it should not change over the calls, so the cached function should be pure i.e.

return values are identical for identical arguments
no side effects




Python provides a built-in cache (since Python 3.9) that is doing what you are doing (example taken from the official documentation).

[...] a thin wrapper around a dictionary lookup for the function arguments.

By looking closely at the documentation of this cache, and its underlying implementation lru_cache, you will get more details about this feature and its limitations.
from functools import cache

@cache
def factorial(n):
    print(f"computing factioral({n}) ...")
    return n * factorial(n-1) if n else 1

print(factorial(4))  # no previously cached result
print("----------")
print(factorial(2))  # just looks up cached value result


# computing factioral(4) ...
# computing factioral(3) ...
# computing factioral(2) ...
# computing factioral(1) ...
# computing factioral(0) ...
# 24
# ----------
# 2

